# Finding an item by iterating through a Go list

Tags: go

I'm attempting to port some C to Go.

I'm essentially looking for something in Go akin to Haskell's `find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a`

I have (roughly) this C for finding an item in a "list" by iterating through it:

```
struct foo {
    struct foo *next;
    char *name;
}

struct foo *foo_list;

// Snip

struct foo *foo = NULL;
for (f = foo_list; f; f = f->next) {
    if (!strcmp("bar", f->name) {
        foo = f;
    }
}

if (foo)
    // Stuff
```

How can I do this nicely and idiomatically in Go?

The "list" is likely to be small; performance characteristics aren't particularly interesting.

Am I likely to want a `slice`, or a `list`? A "list" of `Foo`s or `*Foo`s?

I currently have the following, but I suspect it's not particularly "idiomatic Go"!

```
var FooTable *list.List

// Snip

var foo *Foo = nil

for e := FooTable.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
    if e.Value.(*Foo).name == "bar" {
        foo = e.Value.(*Foo)
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the characteristics of the use of the data structure? You say its small and performance isn't interesting. If it's small, whatever structure is used will likely mostly fit in cache, so simplicity and robustness likely dominate. However, what are the common operations? Does search dominate? Are there many inserts and deletes, even if it remains small? The only awkward operations on slices is delete and insert, and they are still pretty straightforward to write in Go. If the only value is a string, then a slice of strings is probably the simplest. Adding sort is easy too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For idiomatic Go you want a slice of pointers to `Foo` (though if Foo is very small you might choose just a slice of `Foo`), so

```
var foos []*Foo
```

And then for searching

```
var found *Foo
for _, foo := range foos {
    if foo.name == "bar" {
        found = foo
        break
    }
}

if found != nil {
    // stuff
}
```

If you do this a lot you'll wrap it up with some types something like this

```
type Foos []*Foo

func (fs Foos) find(what string) (foo *Foo) {
    for _, foo = range foos {
        if foo.name == what {
            return foo
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then you can do

```
var foos Foos
foo := foos.find("bar")
if foo != nil {
    // something
}
```

PS Nice to answer a question for someone I've actually met!

Comment: Haha it's a small internet! Thanks very much :D

Comment: Please note that if the searched element is not in the slice, your `foo` variable will hold the last element of the slice, certainly not what you want.

Comment: @icza yes you are right! (I followed the OPs code too closely!)  I've fixed that now.